# How to fix the problem of not learning in CNN with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm creating the same network that I had with keras now  with Tensorflow. The thing is that the structure is the same however the neural network is not able to learn and gets stuck in its learnable process.

I've tried everything but I'm not able that the neural network learns.

```py
#We initialize the input data with placeholders
tf_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, HEIGTH, WIDTH, CHANNELS))
tf_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, LABELS))

FILTER1 = (4,4)
STRIDE1 = (2,1)

FILTER2 = (2,1)
STRIDE2 = (1,1)

DEPTH = 32 #32 # Convolutional Kernel depth size == Number of Convolutional Kernels

HIDDEN1 = 128 #1024 # Number of hidden neurons in the fully connected layer
HIDDEN2 = 256 
HIDDEN3 = 512 

keep_prob1 = 0.4
keep_prob2 = 0.25
keep_prob3 = 0.5

#CNN
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([FILTER1[0], FILTER1[1], CHANNELS, DEPTH], stddev=0.001))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([DEPTH]))
#output 100 , 9 , 32
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([FILTER2[0], FILTER2[1], DEPTH, 2*DEPTH], stddev=0.001))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[2*DEPTH]))
#output 
#FC
w3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2496, HIDDEN1], stddev=0.001))
b3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[HIDDEN1]))

w4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([HIDDEN1, HIDDEN2], stddev=0.001))
b4 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[HIDDEN2]))

w5 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([HIDDEN2, HIDDEN3], stddev=0.001))
b5 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[HIDDEN3]))

w6 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([HIDDEN3, LABELS], stddev=0.001))
b6 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[LABELS]))

training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

def logits(data):
    # Convolutional layer 1
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(data, w1, [1, STRIDE1[0], STRIDE1[1], 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.lrn(x,4,bias=0.0, alpha=0.001/9.0, beta=0.75)
    x = tf.nn.max_pool(x, [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.relu(x + b1)
    # Convolutional layer 2
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, w2, [1, STRIDE2[0], STRIDE2[1], 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.lrn(x,4,bias=0.0, alpha=0.001/9.0, beta=0.75)
    x = tf.nn.max_pool(x, [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.relu(x + b2)
    # Fully connected layer
    layer_shape = x.get_shape()
    num_features = layer_shape[1:4].num_elements()
    print(num_features)
    x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, num_features))
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w3) + b3)
    drop_out = tf.nn.dropout(layer_1, keep_prob1)  # DROP-OUT here

    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(drop_out, w4) + b4)
    drop_out = tf.nn.dropout(layer_2, keep_prob2)  # DROP-OUT here

    layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(drop_out, w5) + b5)
    drop_out = tf.nn.dropout(layer_3, keep_prob3)  # DROP-OUT here
    return tf.matmul(drop_out, w6) + b6

# Prediction:
tf_pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits(tf_data))

#We use the categorical cross entropy loss for training the model.
tf_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits(tf_data), 
                                                                 labels=tf_labels))
tf_accuracy = 100*tf.reduce_mean(tf.to_float(tf.equal(tf.argmax(tf_pred, 1), tf.argmax(tf_labels, 1))))

#tf_opt = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer()
LR = 0.001 # Learning rate
tf_opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(LR)
tf_step = tf_opt.minimize(tf_loss)

EPOCHS =100
STEPS = int(train_data.shape[0]/BATCH)  # Number of steps to run

update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session = tf.Session()

session.run(init)
ss = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=STEPS, train_size=BATCH)
ss.get_n_splits(train_data, train_labels)
history = [(0, np.nan, 2)] # Initial Error Measures
for j in range(0,EPOCHS):
    for step, (idx, _) in enumerate(ss.split(train_data,train_labels), start=1):
        fd = {tf_data:train_data[idx], tf_labels:train_labels[idx]}
        session.run(tf_step, feed_dict=fd)

    fd = {tf_data:valid_data, tf_labels:valid_labels}
    valid_loss, valid_accuracy = session.run([tf_loss, tf_accuracy], feed_dict=fd)
    history.append((step, valid_loss, valid_accuracy))
    print('EPOCHS %i \t Valid. Acc. = %f'%(j, valid_accuracy), end='\n')

steps, loss, acc = zip(*history)
```

It gets stuck in the same accuracy even after a high number of steps.

```py
Step 5   Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 10          Valid. Acc. = 52.999996
Step 15          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 20          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 25          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 30          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 35          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 40          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 45          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 50          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 55          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 60          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 65          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 70          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 75          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 80          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 85          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 90          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 95          Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 100         Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 105         Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 110         Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 115         Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
Step 120         Valid. Acc. = 47.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, this is because the `stddev=0.1` you have used in your weights initialization is in fact a *huge* value.

Try with `stddev=0.01` (or even 0.001, if the previous value does not work). You should also initialize your biases to 0, *not* to `1.0`.

One usually doesn't have similar problems in Keras, because the (superb) `glorot_uniform` initializer is used [by default](https://keras.io/layers/core/).

Comment: I tried with these values for the biases however the neural network is still stuck in the learning process, so nothing changed.

Could it be backpropagation is not working well?

Comment: @JoaquinF did you also change the *weight* initialisations? And what's the value of your `LR`?

Comment: I did, however it is still not working. The LR is LR = 0.001. Could it be missing a batch normalization or something like that?